# Difference between these two function formats

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am working on spark and not an expert in scala. I have got the two variants of map function. Could you please explain the difference between them.?

first variant and known format.

first variant

```
val.map( (x,y) => x.size())
```

Second variant -> This has been applied on tuple

```
val.map({case (x, y) => y.toString()});
```

The type of val is `RDD[(IntWritable, Text)]`. When i tried with first function, it gave error as below.

> type mismatch;
>   found :    (org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text) ⇒ Unit 
>   required: ((org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, org.apache.hadoop.io.Text)) ⇒ Unit

When I added extra parenthesis it said,

> Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.

Comment: First variant is a function of two arguments, second is a function of one argument which is supposed to be a tuple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you say:

> The type of val is RDD[(IntWritable, Text)]

so it is a tuple of arity 2 with `IntWritable` and `Text` as components.

If you say

```
val.map( (x,y) => x.size())
```

what you're doing is you are essentially passing in a `Function2`, a function with **two** arguments to the `map` function.  This will never compile because `map` wants a function with **one** argument.  What you can do is the following:

```
val.map((xy: (IntWritable, Text)) => xy._2.toString)
```

using `._2` to get the second part of the tuple which is passed in as `xy` (the type annotation is not required but makes it more clear).

Now the second variant (you can leave out the outer parens):

```
val.map { case (x, y) => y.toString() }
```

this is special scala syntax for creating a `PartialFunction` that immediately matches on the tuple that is passed in to access the `x` and `y` parts.  This is possible because [PartialFunction](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.PartialFunction) extends from the regular [Function1](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Function1) class (`Function1[A,B]` can be written as `A => B`) with one argument.

Hope that makes it more clear :)

Answer (score 0):

I try this in repl:

```
scala> val l = List(("firstname", "tom"), ("secondname", "kate"))
l: List[(String, String)] = List((firstname,tom), (secondname,kate))

scala> l.map((x, y) => x.size)
<console>:9: error: missing parameter type
Note: The expected type requires a one-argument function accepting a    2-Tuple.
  Consider a pattern matching anonymous function, `{ case (x, y) =>  ... }`
          l.map((x, y) => x.size)
```

maybe can give you some inspire.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is a function that takes two arguments and returns a String. This is similar to this example:

```
scala> val f = (x:Int,y:Int) => x + y
f: (Int, Int) => Int = <function2>
```

You can see that the type of `f` is `(Int,Int) => Int` (just slightly changed this to be returning an int instead of a string). Meaning that this is a function that takes two Int as arguments and returns an Int as a result.

Now the second example you have is a syntactic sugar (a shortcut) for writing something like this:

```
scala> val g = (k: (Int, Int)) => k match { case (x: Int, y: Int) => x + y }
g: ((Int, Int)) => Int = <function1>
```

You see that the return type of function `g` is now `((Int, Int)) => Int`. Can you spot the difference? The input type of `g` has two parentheses. This shows that `g` takes one argument and that argument must be a `Tuple[Int,Int]` (or `(Int,Int)` for short).

Going back to your RDD, what you have is an Collection of `Tuple[IntWritable, Text]` so the second function will work, whereas the first one will not work.